# Difference between 'this' , 'activityname.this' and getAplicationContext()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I dont know difference between them, I sometimes use `this`, sometimes `activityame.this`, sometimes `getAplicationContext()` when android needs `context` passed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **this** points to the current object. In this case, an `Activity` Object
- **ActivityName.this** also points to the current `Activity` Object, use it when you are working with an dynamic inner class, such as instantiating a new onClickListener() {}.
- **getApplicationContext()** gets the `Context` reference for the whole application. `Activity` is a Context subclass, but certain things may vary between the appliation Context and the Activity. For the most part though, using the Activity as the Context works fine, I haven't coded anything that needs getApplicationContext() yet.

Answer (score 0):

**this** - is used when you want to reference the object you are currently in. For instance when you're setting up a new class and you want to declare the initial value of your private variables you could do:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String messageToPrint;
    public HelloWorld(String message) {
        this.messageToPrint = message;
    }
}
```

**getApplicationContext()** - Returns the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. Some classes cannot call this, and I've never used it, if I need to get the context of an Activity I'm in, I will use:

```
Context con = getContext();
```

Also I would never use getApplicationContext(); and cast it to your Application class, as you cannot guarantee that it will match-up.

The other one I'm not too sure on ^^